# simple xml read foreach

Tags: php, xml, foreach, xml-parsing

Wonder if you can help for Christmas.

I am trying to read an XML but am having a few issues, basically the foreach structure isnt letting me return the data in the structure I want, and I am not sure of the correct way of doing this. Example below:

```
`<event id="298640100" date="Sat Dec 31 16:00:00 CET 2011">
<market id="9064667" type="1" status="Open" period="FT">
<description>Match Betting</description>
<place_terms>Win only</place_terms>
−
<outcome id="6798861400">
<description>Draw</description>
−
<price id="24532283602">
<decimal>3.5</decimal>
<fractional>5/2</fractional>
</price>
<position>2</position>
</outcome>
−
<outcome id="6798861200">
<description>Bolton Wanderers</description>
−
<price id="24532283402">
<decimal>2.0</decimal>
<fractional>1/1</fractional>
</price>
<position>1</position>
</outcome>
−
<outcome id="6798861300">
<description>Wolves</description>
−
<price id="24532283502">
<decimal>3.6</decimal>
<fractional>13/5</fractional>
</price>
<position>3</position>
</outcome>
</market>
</event>`
```

PHP

```
`<?php
$source = file_get_contents("vc.xml");
$xml = simplexml_load_string($source);
$game = $xml->xpath("//event");
foreach ($game as $event)
{
    echo "<b>Event ID:</b> " . $event['id'] . "<br />";
    echo "<b>Event Date:</b> " . $event['date'] . "<br />";
        {
            foreach ($event->children() as $market)
                {
                    if ($market['period'] == 'FT')
                        {
                            foreach ($market->children() as $outcome) 
                                {
                                    echo "<b>Outcome ID:</b> " . $outcome['id'] . "<br />";
                                    foreach ($outcome->children() as $price) 
                                    {
                                        echo "<b>Price ID:</b> " . $price ['id'] . "<br />";
                                        foreach ($price->children() as $value)
                                            {
                                                echo "<b>Value:</b> " . $value . "<br />";
                                            }
                                    }
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
    echo "<br />";
}
?>`
```

This is basically returning this:

Event ID: 298640100
Event Date: Sat Dec 31 16:00:00 CET 2011
Outcome ID:
Outcome ID:
Outcome ID: 6798861400
Price ID:
Price ID: 24532283602
Value: 3.5
Value: 5/2
Price ID:
Outcome ID: 6798861200
Price ID:
Price ID: 24532283402
Value: 2.0
Value: 1/1
Price ID:
Outcome ID: 6798861300
Price ID:
Price ID: 24532283502
Value: 3.6
Value: 13/5
Price ID:

Ideally I just want to return the following:

Event ID: 298640100
Event Date: Sat Dec 31 16:00:00 CET 2011
Outcome ID: 6798861400
Price ID: 24532283602
Value: 5/2

Any ideas what I am doing wrong and how I could achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Richard

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is what i think you need:

```
foreach ($game as $event)
{
    echo "<b>Event ID:</b> " . $event['id'] . "<br />";
    echo "<b>Event Date:</b> " . $event['date'] . "<br />";
        {
            foreach ($event->children() as $market)
                {
                    if ($market['period'] == 'FT')
                        {
                            foreach ($market->children() as $name => $outcome ) 
                                {
                                    if ( $name != "outcome" )
                                    {
                                      continue;
                                    }
                                    echo "<b>Outcome ID: - $name</b> " . $outcome['id'] . "<br />";
                                    foreach ($outcome->children() as $name => $price) 
                                    {
                                      if ( $name != "price" )
                                      {
                                        continue;
                                      }
                                        echo "<b>Price ID:</b> " . $price ['id'] . "<br />";
                                        foreach ($price->children() as $name => $value)
                                            {
                                                if ( $name != "fractional" )
                                                {
                                                    continue;
                                                }
                                                echo "<b>Value: - $name</b> " . $value . "<br />";
                                                break;
                                            }
                                    }
                                                break;
                                }
                                                break;
                        }
                }
        } 
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for this, I think it would of taken me days to work this out so very much appreciated. Is there a way I could add in the description to this too? I want to also store this to show if the odds are a draw, win or lose. E.G. <description>Bolton Wanderers</description>

Comment: Well, i believe that if you change the if ( $name != "price" ) to if ( $name != "price" && $name != "description" ) you can get the description as well.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 problems here. First, you are using the children() function, which returns all children, not just the specific type you want. This is why you get Outcome ID: 3 times in the begining. Instead of `foreach ($market->children() as $outcome)` you should use `foreach ($market->outcome as $outcome)`.

Second, it seems like you only want the first result. In that case, you shouldn't be using a foreach. the simplexml object is a set of arrays, and you can access an inividual object in the array by its index number. You can get rid of a lot of your code and just grab the first outcome object directly like this:

```
$xml->event->market->outcome[0]
```

You might want to read the official simpleXML documentation http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php